# Need help setting up passenger with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, fedora, ruby-1.9.2

I'm trying to setup passenger with rvm. I keep getting this error

> Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old.
>   Please update them first by running
>   'rvm update --head && rvm reload &&
>   rvm repair all'.

I did that still same problem

> - GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
> - Curl development headers with SSL support... found
> - OpenSSL development headers... found
> - Zlib development headers... found
> - Ruby development headers... found
> - OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
> - RubyGems... found
>
> Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old.
>
> Please update them first by running 'rvm update
>   --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all'.

I'm using Fedora 14, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.7
RVM is installed for multiuser

I also get this error when I do 'passenger start'

> Cannot execute
>   '/home/antarr/.passenger/standalone/3.0.7-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-linux-gcc4.5.1-1002/support/helper-scripts/prespawn
>   http://0.0.0.0:3000': Permission
>   denied (13)

Comment: can you post output of the `rvm update --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all` and `rvm info` and `type rvm | head -1`

Comment: please also run this `find /home -maxdepth 2 -type d -name .rvm` you might have more then one installation of rvm, finally you should be doing RVM update as root either using `sudo` or `su -c`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was having the same issue but found that using the rvmsudo command worked. Instead of

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

try using:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Passenger 3.0.7 is confused by newer versions of `rvm`, but it seems like the instructions are incorrect and it's causing trouble. If the `GEM_HOME` environment variable is not set you get this error.

The correct instructions should be to use your particular version first:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

Although I got the same error as you, after that it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the above solutions work for you and you're getting the `GEM_HOME` warning

delete everything in `.rvmrc`

`rvm get head && rvm reload && rvm repair all`

`gem install passenger`

`passenger-install-apache2-module`

copy/paste the end message into your `apache.conf`

Answer (score 1):

I am still having the same issue with passenger 3.0.19 if I tried to install on gemsets other than default and global. This is soooo troublesome. I have tried many suggestions and even rvm implode, then have everything brand new. but still hitting the brick wall. my forehead almost flatten. Hope not to lose my head!

Luckily, I found myself a fix. I found out that in i am in rvm multiuser envrioment and the issue arised if I switch to user gemset using command: "rvm user gemsets" which basically will create and use .rvm folder in user's home folder. e.g.: /home/.rvm instead of /ur/local/rvm folder. Since I do not know how to switch back and could not find any documention on how to, I did the following steps:

1. remove .rvm folder in the user home folder,
   rm -rf ~username/.rvm
2. added back the user to rvm group (in multi enviroment, every new user need to be added to rvm group)
   sudo usermod -a -G rvm username
3. re-login.

Now, as long as I am using shared rvm gemset folder, phusion passenger wont complaint.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the Permission Denied issue with:

```
chmod a+x /Users/tvd/.passenger/standalone/3.0.7-x86_64-ruby1.9.2-macosx-10.6/support/helper-scripts/*
```

Found it in comment section on the phusion.nl blog:

[Goto Comment on Phusion Blog](http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/04/14/phusion-passenger-3-0-7-released/#div-comment-42751)