# Installing Passenger: use sudo, rvmsudo or nothing...?

Tags: rvm, passenger

Slightly confused regards installing Passenger on my local Mac. I'm using:

RVM version 1.21.2 (stable) 
ruby 2.0.0p195

and downloaded passenger-4.0.5.

There's a discussion on whether to use rvmsudo or not here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyversionmanager/9dnmAsTiHR4

In short, https://www.phusionpassenger.com/download
suggests using `sudo`.

But the rvm page suggests not:
https://rvm.io/integration/passenger

And to make it all a little more confusing, this up-voted SO page suggests using `rvmsudo`!
[Need help setting up passenger with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104086/need-help-setting-up-passenger-with-rvm/8887941)

Dare I ask for a "right" way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you use RVM then either drop `sudo` and Passenger will tell you what to do or use `rvmsudo` and Passenger should do everything for you.

when you do not use rvm it still might depend on more factors, basically `sudo` disables environment including `PATH` which breaks ruby version switchers - so it would work only if you installed ruby from your distribution or manually to system path - which would make ruby work exactly the same with and without `sudo` - in most cases, but not always.

just drop the `sudo`, Passenger will tell you what to do.